# Calculating width in percentage using calc()

Tags: css, width, percentage, calc

I want to calculate the width of an element:

CSS:

```
#progressbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #DDD;
    }
#progress {
    width : calc(100% / 14 * 5);
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0.3em 0.5em 0.2em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<p id="progressbar"><span id="progress">Tag 5</span>von 14</p>
```

This is an exact replication of many examples that I find on the web, yet it does not work (in the most recent version of Firefox) and does not validate (on https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/):

[image]

The code works (but still doesn't validate) when I use DIVs instead of P and SPAN.

What's wrong?

Firebug tells me that the width has been correctly calculated (as 35.7%), but it is not being applied to the element:

[image]

Comment: The parent div should have a width maybe in your case: `.parent { width: 100%; }`. It is working fine to me.

Comment: @ViktorMaksimov Input the code in my question in the w3.org validator. What does it tell you? And yes, it works with a DIV, as in my example, but not with a SPAN element. I'll edit my question in a second.

Comment: The validator is telling you that there is an error because you are using CSS3. Also it is not working on span because the span needs to be `display: block;`. There is no error in your code.

Comment: Thanks, @ViktorMaksimov. If I add `display: inline-block` to the CSS it works fine. (`display: block` causes a break in the line).

Answer (score 1):

Adding **float:left** to your css class will solve your problem.

```
#progress {
width : calc(100% / 14 * 5);
background-color: green;
color: white;
text-align: right;
white-space: nowrap;
padding: 0.3em 0.5em 0.2em;
margin-right: 0.5em;
float:left;
}
```